# Python list as environment variable in Jenkins

Tags: python, list, jenkins

I am trying to set an environment variable in Jenkins that I want my python script in Github to use. I can access variables once they're not a collection but i would like to set a collection variable. In this case, a list.

I have a list variable like:
`list = ["item1","item2"]`

When i try to print it from Jenkins using: 
`print(os.environ['list'])` it prints the whole list as a single string and using `print(type(os.environ['list']))` prints "string".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables are just text. In cases (e.g. the PATH and PYTHONPATH variables), this can be done by using [`os.pathsep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.pathsep) to separate elements of the list. E.g.

```
os.environ['list'] = os.pathsep.join(["item1", "item2"])
```

and then reconstruct

```
print(os.environ['list'].split(os.pathsep))
```

You could also use some serialization standard like JSON.

I don't believe it would work to store the list itself.

Comment: Using `pathsep` could work, but I don't think there's anything traditional about it. There is no guarantee that there is *any* character available that can unambiguously distinguish between two separate list items; that's why many shells provide special array variables instead of relying on delimited strings to represent a list of strings.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. That might work if i wanted to group multiple variables in one list but in my case, I wanted to know how to make a collection variable straight from Jenkins. That does not seem to be possible but I've found a really simple work around. I will post it as the answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Create a string variable in jenkins and then use str.split() in the python script to make a list.

In Jenkins: `jenkinslist = item1 item2 item3`

In Github/python: `pythonlist = os.environ['jenkinslist'].split()`